# Asp.net MVC 4 razor resource you are looking for cannot be displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have dedicated server.after I install iis in windows server 2008.i test my server with html page and it work fine.but when I put my  mvc4 razor project it give this error.why??

***500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.***

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "LoginUser", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
}
**//Webconfig**
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0"/>
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true"/>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false"/>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Shared/ErrorPage"/>
        <sessionState timeout="20"/>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.0"/>
          <authentication mode="Forms"></authentication>
        <pages>
          <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
          </namespaces>
        </pages>
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
            <handlers>
            <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
            <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
                <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
                <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
                <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
                <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
               <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
               <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
            </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
```

Comment: It's hard to say... You get a 500 error, so your application is working, but it generates an error. Can you post the code in your LoginUser action in the Login controller, and maybe the code in the LoginUSer view? I suspect there is an error there.

Comment: Maybe you can set 'Send Errors To Browser' to true in IIS? And maybe remove the DefaultRedirect from Custom errors in your web.config. That should give a better error-message.

Comment: I do that it still give this error

Comment: Okay, can you maybe first try some options listed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error To be sure what is wrong we need the actual error message. This is just a general error message. If you try the options in the link and you get a more detailed error message, post that here.

Comment: ANd in addition to the options in the link, make sure you are not catching the error message in Application_Error() in the Global.Asax file

Comment: this is the error:HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error

Handler "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

Comment: There you go, that is the real error message! Unfortunately, I dont know how to fix that error specifically, but searching for that error should give plenty of possible solutions! (This one is just the first I found, not sure if it applies to you, bet here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162545/handler-extensionlessurlhandler-integrated-4-0-has-a-bad-module-managedpipeli)

Comment: this the answer in this post :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162545/handler-extensionlessurlhandler-integrated-4-0-has-a-bad-module-managedpipeli