# Put/Delete verb result 404 Not Found in WebAPI, only in IIS 10

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, asp.net-web-api2, iis-10

I recently upgrade my Visual studio to 2015 and My windows to 10, so My IIS and IIS Express are changed to version 10.
After this Upgrade, Put/Delete verbs result 404 Not Found in WebAPI.
This is My Delete Action in my WebAPI:

```
public class SlideShowApiController : ApiController
{
    [AcceptVerbs("DELETE")]
    [HttpDelete]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
    {
        ......
    }

}
```

[I found this configuration that work in IIS 8 but not work in IIS 10.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579073/how-to-get-put-and-delete-verbs-to-work-with-webapi-on-iis)

I'm using MVC 5 and WebAPI 2 and My Request Header is:

Accept:*/* 
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch 
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6
AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH:AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.3
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:5
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=vu5joofojlqjs0qd4susdxxa; 
__RequestVerificationToken=hGDy2Mm9BHqAAdGBlTqOzsSFnfvRPBbR87lIKUgkInKLpuFgb4JGcq-c817EtV96VZ8-YbLq85SusCVALYZWrAyAEZZdiiYWEMWaQxFGDCs1; _USERDATA=c099a18b-facf-4b67-9037-1961ffadc326; .ASPXAUTH=22B333AD3B0F591C08C35ACCF1014B4FCB326037EFFA5312382B437A323E58AC5896B3340F972A36AA9C1E3782948745310FBD51E9EB005013ABA934B2E789DA91EC4635E85D7445B635AC05BAE9FB2631E749382A5F8EF75DBFB1E5F84C336A0DAF1663625596AEEE4A14398911AED816E1617C6D6B1D95665F72969ED864A177E5A6458C79E4CD74BF5D950C5B7EA061367CAF450C6762A7F0A0777817E8A0C68C018D6E3E780564503FADEEA0517A29280927D957B1C0A8657EA8C2776198DEB42242D093F2C683F47C05DB04C3B0 
Host:localhost:11631
Origin:http://localhost:11631
Referer:http://localhost:11631/WebManagemenet/SlideShow
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Comment: please post following if you have that information - 1. web api version and mvc (if used) In [Sample implementation of mvc6](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6) as you can see the attributes are specified in different way. 2. Request header from chrome

Comment: Check a typo in referer http://localhost:11631/WebManagemenet/SlideShow

Managemenet  <-- may be a typo

Comment: I couldn't Solve this Problem. Is there any Idea?