# Passed Variables Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am building a small Web API for syncing data and pulling down the objects works great, but pushing my objects up doesn't work no matter what I have tried.

**Edited to reflect some changes:**

Here is my Controller:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public void UpdateTasks([FromBody] string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

Here is my Client code:

```
HttpContent c = new StringContent("1234");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        c.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/QAQC_SyncWebService/Tasks/UpdateTasks/");
        var resp = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, c).Result;
```

I can get a value though if I put it in the URI, but the string content alone doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Set Content-Type: application/json, also use [FromBody] before string

Comment: I did: c.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"); and it's still null.

Comment: Most probably your PUT request is blocked by webserver. Have a look at one of this threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579073/how-to-get-put-and-delete-verbs-to-work-with-webapi-on-iis

Comment: Just as a dirty check, why don't you try using the full URL: `"http://localhost/QAQC_SyncWebService/Tasks/1234"`

Comment: @MarkC. I use the full url and that worked, only if I changed it to a Post action.

Comment: @serhiyb that might be part of the issue, I changed it to a put and I was able to get data through when i used the full url with parameter.

Comment: Have you tried [FromBody] before the string?

Comment: @BradThomas  Nope.  Nothing.

Comment: I added to my answer below, hope that might work for you. Sounds like you might need to adjust the body format slightly to get it to work this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
[HttpPut]
public void UpdateTasks([FromBody]string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Please also note:

3. [FromBody] parameters must be encoded as =value
   The final hurdle remaining is that Web API requires you to pass [FromBody] parameters in a particular format. That’s the reason why our value parameter was null in the previous example even after we decorated the method’s parameter with [FromBody].
   Instead of the fairly standard key=value encoding that most client- and server-side frameworks expect, Web API’s model binder expects to find the [FromBody] values in the POST body without a key name at all. In other words, instead of key=value, it’s looking for =value.
   This part is, by far, the most confusing part of sending primitive types into a Web API POST method. Not too bad once you understand it, but terribly unintuitive and not discoverable.

from http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

Answer (score 1):

The line you are initializing client.BaseAddress looks a bit off.

```
HttpContent c = new StringContent("1234");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
c.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/QAQC_SyncWebService/Tasks/UpdateTasks");
var resp = client.PutAsync(client.BaseAddress, c).Result;
```

The PutAsync method is expecting the full URI, not just a method. Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138168(v=vs.118).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: it really didn't change anything, it's still hitting the debug in the controller, but the parameter is null.  Do parameters need to be named?