# Unable to access Web API 2 web site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have set up a web service - its my first having the web API as a separate site. I can access a web page on the site but when I call a service, (e.g., https://service.sitename.com/api/servicename), I get the following error: Http Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error - Handler "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list. From other site recommendations I installed Asp.Net 4.5 from the Add or Remove Windows program men. But, I get still the same error. Any suggestions?

We are using Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handler "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162545/handler-extensionlessurlhandler-integrated-4-0-has-a-bad-module-managedpipeli)

Comment: I had seen those solutions before. The main one seemed to be installing or registering asp.net 4.5 That has not worked.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your app pool is running .NET 4 and not .NET 2?

Comment: Yes. Its running 4 integrated.