# i buy a asp net website when i try to setup it say HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, webforms

```
i buy a asp net website when i try to setup it say HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
```

here is full error text

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x80070021
Config Error       This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
Config File    \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config
Requested URL      http://localhost:80/live
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\live
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined

Config Source:
   87:     </modules>
   88:     <handlers>
   89:       <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
```

More Information:
This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.

here is the screenshort
https://prnt.sc/ubgp5w

and here is my config file

https://justpaste.it/6yfl8

```
enter code here



      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="Web_AutoSeeding3.My.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
      <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="resources" type="DevExpress.Web.ResourcesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      </system.Web> //debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" 
  -->
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <!--Auth Login-->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="~/index.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <!--End Auth-->
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Printing.v17.1.Core, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.RichEdit.v17.1.Core, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="webopt" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.1, Version=17.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <applicationSettings>
    <Web_AutoSeeding3.My.MySettings>
      <setting name="SavePatch" serializeAs="String">
        <value>D:\GoogleDrive\Project\AutoSeedingFB3\AutoSeedingFB3\bin\Debug</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="sPostWatchLive" serializeAs="String">
        <value>q=%5B%7B%22user%22%3A%22{UserID}%22%2C%22page_id%22%3A%22{PageID}%22%2C%22posts%22%3A%5B%5B%22click_ref_logger%22%2C%5B%220fkQ%22%2C1506598921030%2C%22act%22%2C1506598921028%2C0%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F100011762777288%2Fvideos%2F{VideoID}%2F%23%22%2C%22a%22%2C%22click%22%2C%22-%22%2C%22r%22%2C%22%2F100011762777288%2Fvideos%2F{VideoID}%2F%22%2C%7B%22ft%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22gt%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C429%2C212%2C0%2C1012%2C%22{PageID}%22%2C%22XVideoPermalinkController%22%5D%2C1506598921030%2C1%5D%2C%5B%22logger%3AChatproxyClientErrorsLoggerConfig%22%2C%7B%22status_code%22%3A0%2C%22error_message%22%3A%22ar%3Atransport%20error%22%2C%22topic_prefixes%22%3A%5B%22live%2Fbroadcast%2Fcaption%22%5D%2C%22url%22%3A%22%2Fsub%22%7D%2C1506598921306%2C0%5D%2C%5B%22video_player%22%2C%7B%22logData%22%3A%7B%22ad_client_token%22%3Anull%2C%22available_qualities%22%3A2%2C%22autoplay_eligible%22%3Afalse%2C%22autoplay_setting%22%3A%22off%22%2C%22broadcaster_origin%22%3A%22prn1%22%2C%22projection%22%3A%22flat%22%2C%22player_version%22%3A%22pleasantville%22%2C%22video_id%22%3A%22{VideoID}%22%2C%22player_state%22%3A%22playing%22%2C%22player_origin%22%3A%22permalink%22%2C%22player_suborigin%22%3A%22permalink%22%2C%22playback_is_broadcast%22%3Atrue%2C%22playback_duration%22%3A2596675.01299%2C%22referrer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22streaming_format%22%3A%22dash%22%2C%22video_time_position%22%3A4692.573323%2C%22playback_is_live_streaming%22%3Atrue%2C%22video_channel_id%22%3A%22387437888106301%3A{VideoID}%22%2C%22reaction_video_channel_type%22%3Anull%2C%22fbcdn_pop%22%3Anull%2C%22representation_id%22%3A%22live-md-v%22%2C%22video_bandwidth%22%3A1105553.0206082368%2C%22is_abr_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22feed_position%22%3Anull%2C%22video_chaining_depth_level%22%3A0%2C%22video_chaining_session_id%22%3A%22f3d6548c7962404%22%2C%22channel_eligibility%22%3A%22eligible%22%2C%22autoplay_failure_reasons%22%3A%22%5B%5C%22server_blocked%5C%22%5D%22%2C%22video_play_reason%22%3A%22user_initiated%22%2C%22seq_num%22%3A14%2C%22initial_event%22%3Atrue%2C%22time_ms%22%3A1506598924592%2C%22time%22%3A1506598925%2C%22is_stalling%22%3Afalse%2C%22ft%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22event%22%3A%22played_for_three_seconds%22%2C%22scriptPath%22%3A%22XVideoPermalinkController%22%2C%22source%22%3A%22permalink%22%7D%2C1506598924592%2C0%5D%2C%5B%22ods%3ARTISession%22%2C%7B%22request.error%22%3A%5B1%5D%7D%2C1506598925596%2C0%5D%2C%5B%22ods%3Ajs_error_reporting%22%2C%7B%22error_signal.category.async_error%22%3A%5B2%5D%7D%2C1506598925596%2C0%5D%5D%2C%22trigger%22%3A%22ods%3ARTISession%22%2C%22send_method%22%3A%22ajax%22%7D%5D</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="PassUp" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Auto2</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="My_UID" serializeAs="String">
        <value>100001709940468</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="My_DTSG" serializeAs="String">
        <value>AQFfl1bnjfLk%3AAQH3dmzpNjiX</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="My_Cookies" serializeAs="String">
        <value>sb=Gz_HXhhV1OTLBVShPBogvSTB; datr=Gz_HXkHkHji3FCGxUmGHFaBb; locale=vi_VN; c_user=100001709940468; xs=38%3AwH3J0TIZI7KwWg|AQFfl1bnjfLk%3AAQH3dmzpNjiX%3A2%3A1590116197%3A5043%3A6389; spin=r.1002161425_b.trunk_t.1590378147_s.1_v.2_; fr=0j0SKeoFabt4NAL8Q.AWUXEy247T8Ed4GdaFIrc_BonMI.BexlYI.6F.F7H.0.0.BezHgh.AWXDxurv; _fbp=fb.1.1590459133095.921570233; presence=EDvF3EtimeF1590459251EuserFA21B01709940468A2EstateFDsb2F1590404415074EatF1590409329403Et3F_5bDiFA2user_3a1B03B530076A2EoF1EfF1CAcDiFA2user_3a1B06445833361A2EoF2EfF2CAcDiFA2user_3a1B05850729846A2EoF3EfF3C_5dEutc3F1590458568555G590458568605CEchF_7bCC; wd=1366x282; act=1590459317680%2F2|AQFfl1bnjfLk%3AAQH3dmzpNjiX</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="My_Token" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="sPostWatchLive2" serializeAs="String">
        <value>q=%5B%7B%22user%22%3A%22{UserID}%22%2C%22page_id%22%3A%22{PageID}%22%2C%22posts%22%3A%5B%5B%22video_player%22%2C%7B%22logData%22%3A%7B%22ad_client_token%22%3Anull%2C%22available_qualities%22%3A2%2C%22autoplay_eligible%22%3Afalse%2C%22autoplay_setting%22%3A%22off%22%2C%22broadcaster_origin%22%3A%22prn1%22%2C%22projection%22%3A%22flat%22%2C%22player_version%22%3A%22pleasantville%22%2C%22video_id%22%3A%22{VideoID}%22%2C%22player_state%22%3A%22playing%22%2C%22player_origin%22%3A%22permalink%22%2C%22player_suborigin%22%3A%22permalink%22%2C%22playback_is_broadcast%22%3Atrue%2C%22playback_duration%22%3A2596675.01299%2C%22referrer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22streaming_format%22%3A%22dash%22%2C%22video_time_position%22%3A4692.573323%2C%22playback_is_live_streaming%22%3Atrue%2C%22video_channel_id%22%3A%22387437888106301%3A{VideoID}%22%2C%22reaction_video_channel_type%22%3Anull%2C%22fbcdn_pop%22%3Anull%2C%22representation_id%22%3A%22live-md-v%22%2C%22video_bandwidth%22%3A1105553.0206082368%2C%22is_abr_enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22feed_position%22%3Anull%2C%22video_chaining_depth_level%22%3A0%2C%22video_chaining_session_id%22%3A%22f3d6548c7962404%22%2C%22channel_eligibility%22%3A%22eligible%22%2C%22autoplay_failure_reasons%22%3A%22%5B%5C%22server_blocked%5C%22%5D%22%2C%22video_play_reason%22%3A%22user_initiated%22%2C%22seq_num%22%3A14%2C%22initial_event%22%3Atrue%2C%22time_ms%22%3A1506598924592%2C%22time%22%3A1506598925%2C%22is_stalling%22%3Afalse%2C%22ft%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22event%22%3A%22played_for_three_seconds%22%2C%22scriptPath%22%3A%22XVideoPermalinkController%22%2C%22source%22%3A%22permalink%22%7D%2C1506598924592%2C0%5D%2C%5B%22ods%3ARTISession%22%2C%7B%22request.error%22%3A%5B1%5D%7D%2C1506598925596%2C0%5D%2C%5B%22ods%3Ajs_error_reporting%22%2C%7B%22error_signal.category.async_error%22%3A%5B2%5D%7D%2C1506598925596%2C0%5D%5D%2C%22trigger%22%3A%22ods%3ARTISession%22%2C%22send_method%22%3A%22ajax%22%7D%5D</value>
      </setting>
    </Web_AutoSeeding3.My.MySettings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <devExpress>
    <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" styleSheetTheme="" theme="" customThemeAssemblies="" baseColor="" font="" />
    <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="true" />
    <settings accessibilityCompliant="false" bootstrapMode="Bootstrap3" doctypeMode="Html5" rightToLeft="false" checkReferencesToExternalScripts="true" protectControlState="true" ieCompatibilityVersion="edge" />
    <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl="" />
  </devExpress>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: CD8E53D2-B177-494B-AE08-1CEEF98E43D7-->
```

please help me to run this

thanks

Comment: Is it Asp.net web forms or Asp.net MVC or ASP.Net core ?

Comment: hi i don't know please check folder https://prnt.sc/ubiacd

Comment: Ok, it's asp.net web forms

Comment: please help me to run this

Comment: Follow something like this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047873/unable-to-fix-error-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path

Comment: It seems to have a problem with the line `<remove name="ChartImageHandler" />`. Have you tried just removing it? Seems like the most obvious low effort troubleshooting step.

Comment: i try this but not work still same please help me to fix this thanks

Comment: Really? It's still the same error message, even though the line is now gone? I find that hard to believe. It would have changed somehow, even if it was just to complain about a different line.

Comment: do you have check that the web.config is on the root directory of your site, and no other web.config like this one exist on parent directories ?

Comment: yes you can check also https://prnt.sc/ubjybo

Comment: @JuwelRana Can you create a basic Asp.Net web forms solution and try to host

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath can you give me a test file thanks

Comment: @JuwelRana https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kEzgCaJTU90KsvQd5FJlT-VuFaQXb9fm/view?usp=sharing